# "Too Many Redirects" when using RedirectMatch 301 in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm creating a new website in WordPress for a client. The old homepage was at `domain.com/index.htm`, and on the new website the homepage is at `domain.com/`. I'm trying to create a 301 redirect in .htaccess to redirect users from the old homepage URL to the new homepage URL, so I added `RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.htm$ /`. But this gives me a "Too Many Redirects" error when I go to the homepage.

My complete .htaccess file is below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.htm$ /

# Force non-www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Currently I'm testing on a site with a subdomain before taking the new site live, so the URL is subdomain.domain.com

If the answer is obvious, I apologize. I don't have much experience with redirects and I haven't been able to find anything helpful online. I've tried things like including the full URL: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.htm$ subdomain.domain.com/` but nothing seems to work and I still get the error.

Comment: Your redirect seem to be working fine. Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Combining Redirect directives with mod_rewrite is something I’d rather avoid, it is hard to tell in which order those things get evaluated then. Plus, you need to do your custom rewriting before the general WP stuff - it rewrites anything that doesn’t match a file or folder to its index.php, and due to the [L] flag any rules further down won’t even get applied any more then, so neither your force non-www nor force HTTPS stuff would do anything in that case.